# Why do the registry APIs indicate that there are zero subkeys?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to read the number of subkeys in a registry key.

The code ran on Windows 7 Home Edition in an administrator's account.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winreg.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int number_of_arguments, char* arguments[]) {
    HKEY handle;
    DWORD number_of_subkeys;
    LSTATUS result = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
        0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &handle);
    if (result != 0) {
        cout << "Failed to open registry key: " << result;
    }
    result = RegQueryInfoKeyA (handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
            &number_of_subkeys, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (result != 0) {
        cout << "Failed to read registry key: " << result;
    }
    else if (result == 0) {
        cout << "Number of subkeys: " << number_of_subkeys;
    }   
    while (1 == 1) {
    }
}
```

The output should be two instead of zero.

Comment: On my machine, that key doesn't have any subkeys, for what it's worth. Did you mean to query the number of values, perchance?

Comment: 32 bit process, registry redirector, at a guess

Comment: My guess is that it is probably *both* of those problems!

Comment: @MartinBonner Also, `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` lets you read values but not enumerate subkeys; you need `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS` for that. So we're up to three problems now.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit programs on 64-bit? This Registry will be redirected to `SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run`. There should be no subkeys under this key on your machine. You need to insert the KEY_WOW64_64KEY parameter on the first `RegOpenKeyExA`.Or use `RegDisableReflectionKey` to disable redirection directly.